# Why is the "noise or pointless" close option still enabled here?

Tags: support, status-completed, close-reasons

[image: Why is this still here]

So why do we still have "noise or pointless" as a close option on Meta Super User (and Meta Server Fault) and nowhere else? I've just noticed that the "not a real question" option is missing.

<sup>They say a picture is worth a thousand words, but I've got to add something here to ensure I get this past the low quality heuristics</sup>

Comment: `not a real question` was replace by `not constructive`...Also, the `noise or pointless` option is usually just for meta sites, you won't see it on the main sites, as I'm sure you already know...

Comment: @studiohack - check the close reasons on MSO or any other meta site. MSO only has 4 reasons (the 1st four here) other metas have 5 (the 1st four + not a real question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have synced the close reasons on meta.su and meta.sf with the rest of the network.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow still only has four though....